# Проверка на ввод только чисел С++

Tags: c++, обработка-ошибок

Как сделать проверку для 3-х переменных на то, что бы это был ввод только чисел?
Code:

```
// hms_to_secs.cpp
// convert hour, minuts, second to seconds
// input for example: 23 59 59
// output: 86399

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
long hms_to_secs(int&, int&, int&);     // prototype
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    int h, m, s;                        // hour, minute, second
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter (hours minuts seconds): " << endl;
        cin >> h >> m >> s;
        for (int x = 0; x < 50; ++x) cout << "~";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Result: " << hms_to_secs(h, m, s) << " seconds" << endl << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < 50; ++x) cout << "~";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return false;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
long hms_to_secs(int& hours, int& minuts, int& second)
{
    unsigned long sec;
    sec = (hours * 3600) + (minuts * 60) + second;
    cout << "Addres of hours: " << &hours << "[value: " << *(&hours) << "]"
        << "\nAddres of minuts: " << &minuts << "[value: " << *(&minuts) << "]"
        << "\nAddres of second: " << &second << "[value: " << *(&second) << "]";
    cout << "\n\n\nSIZE OF SEC: " << sizeof(sec) << endl;
    return sec;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, использовал такую заготовку при выполнении работ нерадивым студентам :)

В одном флаконе приглашение, проверка на ввод именно числа и диапазона этого числа (типа, минуты - от 0 до 59...)

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
}
```

Думаю, если что - допилите напильником?... :)

Comment: Спасибо) 
Принцип понял)

Comment: Если ответ устроил - закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ ("птичка" слева).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double digit{0};
    std::cin >> digit;
    if(std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Not num" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "done! num is: " << digit << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

или 
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte
Тут можно найти необходимую ф-ию и написать обработку входных данных